# .Net 6 Ocelot 18.0 API Gateway returns 404 in preflight call from server

Tags: c#, .net, ocelot

I have been using Ocelot 18.0.0 as API Gateway. It's working fine in local environment but in server it is working fine for some calls and returning 404 (Not found) error for some calls.

API Gateway connected with 5 micro services(.Net 6) and all are working fine in server.

If I try it from postman it always working fine. But when I call from angular application it's working some time and not working some time.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

```
// cors policy configured
services.AddCors(options => 
{ 
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", x => x
        .WithOrigins("https://xx.xxx.com",
                     "https://xxx-xx.xxx.com",
                     "http://localhost:4200")              
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithExposedHeaders("x-filename"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// global cors policy
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();

// ocelot api gateway
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Ocelot.json file

```
{
    "Routes": [ 
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/xxxServer/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
                {
                    "Host":"localhost",
                    "Port":9000
                }                
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/authentic/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false           
        },                
        
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/{aaaMgmt}/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
            {
                "Host":"localhost",
                "Port":9001
            }                
            ],            
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/aaamgmt/{aaaMgmt}/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,  
            "AuthenticationOptions": {  
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "AuthKey",  
                "AllowedScopes": []  
            }
        },
        
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/{bbbadmin}/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
            {
                "Host":"localhost",
                "Port":9002
            }                
            ],            
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/bbb/{bbbadmin}/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,  
            "AuthenticationOptions": {  
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "AuthKey",  
                "AllowedScopes": []  
            }  

        },

        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/{dddadmin}/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
            {
                "Host":"localhost",
                "Port":9003
            }                
            ],            
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/ddd/{dddadmin}/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,  
            "AuthenticationOptions": {  
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "AuthKey",  
                "AllowedScopes": []  
            }  

        },

        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/{ccc11admin}/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
            {
                "Host":"localhost",
                "Port":9004
            }                
            ],            
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/ccc11/{ccc11admin}/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,  
            "AuthenticationOptions": {  
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "AuthKey",  
                "AllowedScopes": []  
            }  

        },

        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate":"/{ddd11admin}/{allendpoints}",
            "DownstreamScheme":"https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts":[
            {
                "Host":"localhost",
                "Port":9005
            }                
            ],            
            "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/ddd11/{ddd11admin}/{allendpoints}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod":[ "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ],
            "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,  
            "AuthenticationOptions": {  
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "AuthKey",  
                "AllowedScopes": []  
            }  

        }
       
    ],   

    "GlobalConfiguration": {
      "RequestIdKey": "OcelotRequestId",
      "AdministrationPath": "https://localhost:5001"          
    }
}
```

I tried by replacing app.UseOcelot().Wait() to app.UseOcelot() but still getting the issue.

Comment: Please show your `CorsPolicy` configuration and `ocelot.json` file content

Comment: Hi Artur - Thanks for your reply. I have posted the CorsPolicy and ocelot.json file. If you need any other information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

you have to update your programe.cs to the following:

```
app.UseRouting(); //Without this line the default "Hello World" page will not be displayed
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers()); //Without this line the default "Hello World" page will not be displayed

app.UseOcelot().Wait(); //When any request it made, it goes through ocelot

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
```